# CSS child width by cursor position on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rating

I'm trying to make CSS/jQuery based rating. This is what I have till now: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/km2p1ebb/).

```
<div class="rating">
     <div class="active" style="width: 70%"></div>
</div>
```

I need to change percent of `.rating > .active` when mouse cursor is on the parent (.rating). For example I will move my mouse 50% to right so `.active` will have 50% width.

[Example with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/km2p1ebb/2/)

```
$('.rating').on('mouseover', function(){    
    var position = $(this).position();

    $(this).find('.active').css('width', position.left);
});
```

But it always returns me "8". So I don't know why.

Comment: Please post the javascript that you tried.

Comment: just a moment, pasting to fiddle

Comment: The feature that you are trying to create should be created in some other way. Because you will face difficulty in reading the rating and sending it to the back end which ends up in a confusion

Comment: added with JS of my concept what I want. Problem is that I can't imagine how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at **[JQuery raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty)**.

Comment: I see what you're doing (with Jake's answer) but don't you want the stars to snap to half or full stars?

Comment: @Popnoodles the stars width should inherit by percent of rating. for example total rating is 4.1 so content should have 82% width (I think so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/km2p1ebb/3/

```
$(".rating").mousemove(function(e) {
    var gLeft = $(this).offset().left,
        pX = e.pageX;
    $(this).find('.active').width(pX - gLeft);
});
```

Comment: this is great solution :) but how to get rating in numbers? when 1 star = 2 points. 5 stars = 10 points

Comment: I found a solution but it fails at counting, it should be more accurated - http://jsfiddle.net/km2p1ebb/5/ any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/km2p1ebb/6/ Quick implementation, just get exact size of width each star and replace "16" with the width

Comment: nice work @Jake but it must count and half of star for rating, for example 3 when this is only 1.5 stars hovered.

Comment: Remove the round function and you'll get it in increment of 1/16s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87024/discussion-between-jake-and-arnas-pecelis).

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/km2p1ebb/4/)**

Added `mousemove` event. `position.left` means the position of the div. If you subtract the mouse x co-ordinate position from position left, you'll get the correct value.

```
$('.rating').on('mouseover mousemove', function(e){    
    var position = $(this).position();
    $(this).find('.active').css('width', e.pageX - position.left);
});

$('.rating').on('mouseout', function (e) {
    var position = $(this).position();
    $(this).find('.active').css('width', '70%'); //reset to initial value if not clicked.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could not reinvent the wheel and use existing jQuery plugin, for example [jQuery Raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/dag2zo2b/1/)

```js
$('.js-raty').raty({
    path: 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/demo/images/',
    score: 4,
    click: function(score) {
        $('.js-points').text(score * 2);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/jquery.raty.js"></script>
<link href="http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/jquery.raty.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="js-raty"></div>
<div>Points: <span class="js-points">8</span></div>
```